# Getting these paterns using for loop in PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to create a for loop that would make a pattern like this.

```
* two tree four five
one * tree four five
one two * four five
one two tree * five
one two tree four *

* * tree four five
one * * four five
one two * * five
one two tree * *

* * * four five
one * * * five
one two * * *

* * * * five
one * * * *

* * * * *
```

Instead I end up finding this [How to get these patern using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969700/how-to-get-these-patern-using-for-loop)

The guys are using JavaScript:

```
const temp = ["one","two","three","four","five"];
let arrayResult = []
for(let i = 0; i< temp.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j< temp.length - i; j++){
        let tempArr = temp.slice();
        let stars = Array(i+1).fill('*')
        tempArr.splice(j, i+1, ...stars);
        arrayResult.push(tempArr);
    }}
```

I wanted to pull this of using php but I can't seem to get it work even with array_splice()

```
$temp = array("one","two","three","four","five");
$arrayResult = array();
for($i = 0; $i< count($temp); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j< count($temp) - $i; $j++){
        $tempArr = $temp.slice();
        $stars = Array($i+1).fill('*')
        $tempArr.splice($j, $i+1, ...$stars);
        $arrayResult [] = $tempArr;
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
<?php
$temp = array("one","two","three","four","five");
$arrayResult = array();
for($i = 0; $i< count($temp); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j< count($temp) - $i; $j++){
        $tempArr = $temp; //assign original array to temp variable
        $newArray[$i+1] = '*'; //create a new star array
        array_splice($tempArr,$j, $i+1,$newArray); //fill the stars into temp array
        $arrayResult [] = $tempArr; //assign temp array to final output array
    }

}
print_r($arrayResult);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/9KRYJ

Note: If you run the script and do `console.log` of each variable, you can easily understand what's going on and how to convert it to PHP code. I did the same way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        
$result = [];
$temp = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($temp) - $i; $j++) {
        $tempArr = $temp;
        $stars[$i+1] = "*";
        array_splice($tempArr, $j, $i+1, $stars);
        array_push($result, $tempArr);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$template=explode(' ','one two tree four five');
//$template=['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four', 'five'];
for($i=5;($i-->0);)for($pos=0;$pos++<=$i;)  $res[]=array_replace($template,array_fill($pos-1,5-$i,'*') );


echo '<pre>';
//print_r($res);
var_dump($res);
echo '</pre>';
```